# (node:16448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try connection from Node to MongoDB but i got this error:

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16448) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here is my file. Of course without username and password that is ok.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoPractice =require('./mongo')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/products',mongoPractice.createProduct);

app.get('/products');

app.listen(3000);
```

mongo.js

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const url ='xxxxxx'

const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    const newProduct = {
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price
    };
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
  
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const db = client.db();
      const result = db.collection('products').insertOne(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.json({message: 'Could not store data.'});
    };
    client.close();
  
    res.json(newProduct);
  };
  
  const getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
  
    let products;
  
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const db = client.db();
      products = await db.collection('products').find().toArray();
    } catch (error) {
      return res.json({message: 'Could not retrieve products.'});
    };
    client.close();
  
    res.json(products);
  };
  
  exports.createProduct = createProduct;
  exports.getProducts = getProducts;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "refresh-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

if i try this package.json then work, but it is deprecated:

```
{
  "name": "refresh-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing an await front of the database insertion:

```
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const db = client.db();
      const result = await db.collection('products').insertOne(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.json({message: 'Could not store data.'});
    };
    client.close();
  
    res.json(newProduct);
  };
```